# Is the heart more relaxed when stretched or contracted, and how does it affect cross-bridge interactions?

Tags: human-physiology

In the heart, are stretched muscles during the diastole more relaxed or are the contracted muscles more relaxed? Depending on the answer, are there then more cross-bridge interactions in cardiac muscle cells when the heart is stretched or contracted?

Comment: Can you clarify your question? What do you mean by "more relaxed". There are a few things to consider here: the contracted or relaxed state of cardiac muscle, as well as the baseline stretch in that muscle. But your use of "relaxed" in your question isn't standard.

Comment: Well that is the question itself. When the heart is contracted, is that when it is more relaxed? Or, is it more relaxed when it is expanded? Which state is the resting state of a heart?

Comment: Relaxed is the opposite of contracted, so when it is contracted it is exactly not relaxed, by definition. Are you referring to the pathological state of stretching that occurs in some forms of heart failure, e.g., dilated cardiomyopathy?

Comment: It's completely possible I have terminology mixed up, I'm not biology expert and different sources gave conflicting descriptions. I'm not referring to any kind of disease, what I want to know is which state, expanded or "smaller", is the heart's resting state when it is not exerting energy to pump blood, and thus, which other state must then be the one that takes more energy to allow more cross-bridge interactions to maintain. Is the heart more relaxed when it is expanded? Or when it is...I guess I can only say "smaller" since contracted could be for either direction.

Comment: Contracted literally means to shrink in size: "contracted" cannot mean "either direction"

Comment: @BryanKrause I used to think that too before Dan commented. But, for instance, when muscles in your biceps contract, part of them becomes shorter, but then another part of them bulges up and becomes larger. So muscle "contracting" could cause surround tissue to expand.

Comment: Nothing in Dan's comment suggests that contracted could mean anything but shrunken in size.

Comment: @BryanKrause They said relaxed is the opposite of contracted, but there is nothing in biology that says a larger or smaller structure has to be either in general. Just hold out your fingers, they are moderately suspended from your hand, not completely dropping to a 90 degree angle, but not completely risen up either. When the muscles in your fingers contract, your finger can either rise, *Or Also* curl. Either way, a muscle "contraction" occurs.

Comment: I should correct to say length instead of size: length is the important dimension of size in the context of muscle action. When your fingers extend that is not because the muscles that bend your fingers are lengthening in some way, it's because another muscle pulls the back of your finger taut.

Comment: @BryanKrause You mean the length of the sacromere. Yes, I imagine that always decreases during muscle contraction which is what allows the ratcheting to occur in the first place based on what I had found.

Comment: @BryanKrause But your finger description is exactly my point. Even though muscles always contract to exert force, they can affect surrounding tissue in different ways. So, I can't simply say that the heart shrinks just because I read cardiac muscles contract since as you pointed out, contraction can lead to different kinds of movement, more information is needed.

Comment: I mean the length of the whole muscle. More information is not needed to answer your question "Is the heart more relaxed when stretched or contracted": you are asking "Is the heart longer when it is longer or shorter?"

Comment: @BryanKrause We just agreed that just because one muscle contracts, it doesn't mean all the surrounding tissue shrinks. In the finger example, some of the tissue shrinks, but also the opposite part of it expands. So, simply stating cardiac muscles contract isn't enough to be 100% sure that that is what causes the heart to shrink in size, especially when we're dealing with all kinds of different contractions in different 3D directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The muscular portion of the heart is comprised of [cardiac myocytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cardiac_muscle_cell), elongated cells filled with bundles of actin and myosin called sarcomeres. These cells are similar in many respects to skeletal muscles, but are shorter, have only one nucleus, and slightly different isoforms (versions) of the proteins involved. The purpose of this cell, like the skeletal muscle cell, is contraction, or *shortening* on activation.

This image of cardiac muscle cells shows how full they are with long bands of proteins (proteins stain pink).

[image]

Because the heart is a muscular chamber, instead of simply a band of muscle (like the bicep), the relevant dimension for the organ is volume instead of length. Where your bicep gets shorter when it contracts (and pulls your forearm toward your upper arm, bending at the elbow joint), when your heart muscle contracts, it twists and squeezes against the fibrous part of the organ, decreasing the volume of the chamber.

Since there is no air in a healthy live heart, when the heart contracts, reducing the volume of the container, the blood is forced out of the heart (ejection) through whatever opening is available. This is called systole. When the heart relaxes, the volume of the container increases, and blood enters the container through whatever opening is available. this is called diastole.

[image]

Now, how is this related to cross-bridge interactions?

The mechanism for contraction itself, in both skeletal and cardiac muscle, is cross-bridge cycling. Those pink bundles of actin, myosin, and associated proteins in the picture above form bonds, change conformation, break bonds, change conformation, and form new bonds:
[image]

This cross-bridge cycling **occurs during contraction** when $Ca^{++}$ enters the cell as part of the cardiac action potential. Relaxation occurs when $Ca^{++}$ concentrations decrease, through the action of the $Ca^{++}$-ATPase, causing cross bridge interactions to decrease.

Comment: Okay, so just to make it clear before I select it as the answer, when the heart is expanded, that is it's natural resting state, and when the cardiac muscles exert force through contraction, it is only to shrink the size of the heart? I just want to make sure on whether it is the expanding or the shrinking that requires the cardiac muscle to contract, and so far it seems like it's the shrinking action.

Comment: You are correct. Contraction causes the volume inside the heart to decrease (the volume inside the chamber shrinks).

Comment: You're putting a lot of work into the question and I appreciate that, but I don't want you to over-invest when I am focused so much on a singular question. I can infer the cross-bridge interactions depending on what the answer is and I am familiar with the theory behind it.